# Type mismatch error in excel VBA

Tags: excel, if-statement, range, type-mismatch, vba

Need some advice, getting this error when I try run this macro i get a mismatch error.

The "InsertNAtoBlanks" is self explanatory, I just need this IF statement to read a specific column in that table and if there are blanks in any of the cells run the "InsertNAtoBlanks" macro, if not then move on to the next step in the macro.

```
Dim x As ListObject
Dim z As Range
Dim Bcell As Range

Set x = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table6")
Set z = x.DataBodyRange.Columns(11)

For Each Bcell In z
If Bcell.Value <> Empty Then

Run "InsertNAtoBlanks"

 Else

'Contiue on with macro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there are blanks

Change

```
If Bcell.Value <> Empty Then
```

to

```
If Bcell.Value <> "" Then
```

Or to

```
If Len(Trim(Bcell.Value)) <> 0 Then
```

The `Empty` keyword is used as a `Variant` subtype. It indicates an uninitialized variable value.

Your code can be written as

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim x As ListObject
    Dim z As Range
    Dim Bcell As Range

    Set x = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table6")
    Set z = x.DataBodyRange.Columns(11)

    For Each Bcell In z.Cells
        If Bcell.Value <> "" Then
            Run "InsertNAtoBlanks"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Siddaharth, I tried both and I still got a Run-time error '13': type mismatch

Comment: See the updated post. You may have to refresh the page

Comment: I used the code provided, I didnt get the type mismatch error like before. So thats good news, when i ran the macro i got the error "no cells were found". I added else into the code and i still get the same erro.

Comment: `i got the error "no cells were found"` on which line did you get that error?

Comment: you cannot get the error or more than one line at any give moment. So which line are you getting the error? `For Each Bcell In z.Cells` OR `If Bcell.Value <> "" Then` OR `Run "InsertNAtoBlanks"`

Comment: Without seeing your else part, i cannot comment :)

Comment: I didnt know how to show you the code on the comments, so i just added an answer below with all of the code and error it was highlighting:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43332/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-michaelacruz)